# Read multiple tables in Excel sheet using python

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have an excel sheet which has multiple tables in it, using openpyxl .tables method to read the tables but getting empty list eventhough there are two tables but it return empty. Is there a way to achieve it in python. I need to further process the data from these tables after extracting it into a dataframe. But the tables itself is not getting detected. Any pointers on this would be helpful.

from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd

#read file
wb = load_workbook('29.xlsx')

#access specific sheet
ws = wb["Sheet1"]

print(ws.tables.items())

---

Below is the structure of the Excel sheet.

[image]

Comment: Worksheet tables are really handy ranges for formatting, etc. They do not themselves contain any data and in any case, it doesn't look like these are worksheet tables.

Comment: In that case some kind of parsing of the excel sheet to obtain only the tables from the read dataframe, using dataframe.itertuples()

Comment: It sounds to me like you're relying on Pandas to do a lot of guesswork for you. Surely, it's easier to find the ranges of the tables yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Parsing the dataframe read, able to get only the tables as ouptut as given below,
is there a better way to handle this, so it works for other excel files of similar kind with multiple tables in it.

```
from operator import index
import xlrd
import pandas
import math

df = pandas.read_excel('29.xlsx', engine='openpyxl',index_col=None)
noofColumsn = df.shape[1]
a_list = []
for i in df.itertuples():    
    j = 0
    for x in i:             
        if(pandas.isna(x)):
            j = j + 1
            if(j == (noofColumsn -1)):
                break
    if(j < (noofColumsn -1)):
        list(i)
        print(i)        
        a_list.append(i)                 
df1 = pandas.DataFrame(a_list)
del df1[df1.columns[0]]
print(df1.head(1))

df1.to_excel("output.xlsx",header=None,index = False)
```

[image]